# C# WPF: Adjust Source Values Being Bound to Target

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a rectangle,`rect` in a UserControl called `DisplayLabel` whose width is bound to the `ActualWidth` of the MainWindow. Is it possible to make it so `rect.width` is bound to something like `MainWindow.ActualWidth -50`? This way the rectangle is always 50 pixels less than the width of the screen.

Here is the binding in the code behind.

```cs
           Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
           rect.Fill = Brushes.Aquamarine;
           rect.Height = 20;
           Binding widthBinding = new Binding("ActualWidth");
           widthBinding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(MainWindow), 1);
           rect.SetBinding(Rectangle.WidthProperty, widthBinding);


           UCgrid.Children.Add(rect);
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949320/wpf-bind-scale-of-one-element-to-the-scale-of-another) SO post suggests scaling afterward to change the size of the object. Is there a way a `ScaleTransform` could achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom ValueConverter and even provide the amount to subtract as the converter parameter:

```
public class SubtractionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Contrived example - make sure to type check before using 'value'
        return (float)value - (float)parameter)
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then in your C# (or XAML):

```
widthBinding.Converter = new SubtractionConverter();
widthBinding.ConverterParameter = 50f;
```